# hover an image makes it darker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Just need to know how hovering an image makes it darker? using jquery /css.

my css

```
.img-files{
    background:url("/Images/syzs.png") no-repeat; 
    position:absolute;
    background-size:90%;       
    width: 100px;       
    height: 150px;
    text-indent: -9999px; 
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: by using 'filter' you can achieve this

Comment: see this [link] (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-filter/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of the `:hover` pseudo class and the `::after` pseudo element.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rCj6L/)**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://aux3.iconpedia.net/uploads/69290979.png" />
</div>

div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
div:hover::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: +1 for a few times i have seen hover and after are being used together.

Answer (score 5):

You can make it better using black background with opacity property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfwy9/)

```
.dark {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
}

.dark img {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.dark:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, what I will be doing is put a black element overlaying the image, instead you're doing it in reverse.

Comment: @Etjie Exactly, and as opacity affects all nested elements, so I went for this

Answer (score 1):

Use `opacity`:

```
.img-files {opacity: 0.5;}
.img-files:hover {opacity: 1;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/V7cFn/

Comment: @user1869928 Can you show an example? I guess you might need to use filters.

Comment: ALright.. I'll show  one but here it's like a video link .. I just need that darkness..http://hocusfocus.no/

Comment: @user1869928 Are you looking for this? http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/

Comment: @PraveenKumar muhaha mine beats yours :p

Comment: Not sure but this might help http://www.noeltock.com/tilt-shift-css3-jquery-plugin/